# Unit Testing Frameworks for C:  Comparison

Tags: c, tdd

I am a ruby programmer and I really like to do TDD. Right now, I am programming a little bit in C, but I like my tools and the way I program with ruby. So, I am searching for a framework to do unit tests in C. What do you can tell me about it?

I already found some options, like: cunit, cmockery, CuTest and others. The problem is, I don't know how to evaluate the best one. I am writing a simple compiler for my compilers college course.

Could you help me?

Comment: I would like to have something simple,as CUTest (http://cutest.sourceforge.net/) but I also would like to have something with a great output, as Cutter (http://cutter.sourceforge.net/).

But it really seems that I can't have both.

Comment: I'd like to see an answer to this question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any C or C++ unit testing framework.  Its easy enough to call C functions from C++.

My opinion is that you want to have as little output as possible from your tests.  ie if everything is OK, it should print `'100% passed'`.  Otherwise it should only print out details of test failures.

see [xprogramming.com](http://xprogramming.com/software) (original link broken; [here it is on the way back machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20090430133724/http://xprogramming.com/software)), scroll down to the Unit Testing table and look for the `C Language` or `C++` frameworks.  The most 'standard' it seems is cppUnit.

Comment: In many environments that use C, you can *only* use C. So C++ frameworks probably aren't useful here, especially since the OP is talking about a compiler course in college which likely is not going to let him use C++ in his project.

Comment: Its true that, for example, an embedded C compiler which runs under windows, but targets a microcontroller only compiles C, but it would be easy enough to compile your code in, say, Visual Studio.  You can then write tests in C++ with whatever C++ unit testing framework you want.

Answer (score 5):

[Unity](https://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity), a test framework for C has a rich set of assertions including bitwise and memory block comparisons. If you're not dealing with a large legacy codebase I'd recommend using [Ceedling](https://www.throwtheswitch.org/ceedling), the parent project of Unity. Ceedling builds your Unity tests, production code and integrates a nice mocking framework called [CMock](https://www.throwtheswitch.org/cmock). CMock can auto-generate a mock/substitute for a module from it's public interface header.

There's a video showing you how to [get started with Ceedling and Unity](http://vimeo.com/doughgle/test-driven-development-for-c-with-ceedling). (DISCLAIMER: I created the video).

An alternative, is [CppUTest](http://cpputest.github.io/manual.html). It compiles to 1 static library (2 if you want to use it's mocking framework, [CppUMock](http://cpputest.github.io/mocking_manual.html)). Tests are written in C++ and it integrates with your existing makefile project. It also offers memory leak detection alternatives for malloc/free, new/delete. By comparison, it's assertions are not as comprehensive as Unity, but it's probably better suited to testing C/C++ legacy projects.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [gtest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) and found it to be pretty easy to use (It is C++ though). Really though, it doesn't matter too much which one you pick. Just pick one and learn it.

Comment: In many environments that use C, you can *only* use C. So C++ frameworks probably aren't useful here, especially since the OP is talking about a compiler course in college which likely is not going to let him use C++ in his project.

Comment: AFAIK gtest can also be used with C, as it only makes use of macros, so there shouldn't be any C++ dependency.

Answer (score 2):

There's a wiki page which lists info on around 20 [C compatible unit testing frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C).  While it may not be enough info to make a decision, it is a decent starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that nobody has mentioned [FFF (Fake Function Framework)](https://github.com/meekrosoft/fff).  Its lightweight with a single header file, and various use cases are well documented (passing function pointers, return by reference, etc).

Disclaimer: I've not started using it, but having looked over alternatives, this is the one I'm choosing.